How to migrate a single item(eg: user story) from TFS to devops
I want to migrate bugs, user stories, task and features form TFS to Devops. TO do this I created a config file and gave below srring in WIQLQueryBit to migrate a single user story.
"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('User Story') AND [System.Id] = 71863",

While I am ruining this, Cmd showing  "Loading 27870 Work Items" and taking more time.
How to migrate a single work item? is it possible.

Set the value of WIQLQueryBit like as below:
"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.Id] = 71863"

Or directly set the value of WIQLQuery like as below:
"WIQLQuery": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.Id] = 71863 ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc"


Have you tried the WIQL Queries shared above? Do they work for you?
"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.Id] = 71863"
or
"WIQLQuery": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.Id] = 71863 ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc"
@Sijith
